# Can't figure out how to get a complicated array from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My friend built a database to manage equipments that we own, but I don't know how I can get arrays from collection-documents-collection

I've tried looking through the Firestore documents

```
    db.collection("users").document("borrow").addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        let data = documentSnapshot?.data() as! [String:Any]
    }


    db.collection("users").document("borrow").getDocument() { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in documentSnapshot!.data()! {
                print("\(document.self) => \(document.key)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Like in the picture below, inside the collection there's

equipments-VR-E1001
[image: Firestore screenshot]
How can I get the array of E1001? Is it easier if I get the value with `[String:[String:[String:Any]]]` ? Or is there an easier way to do this

Comment: I suggest adding collection in Borrow with VR, then add documents like 1001, 1002, etc and grab data using that way..

Comment: Yep, I do have "equipment" above VR, but I couldn't figure out how to grab E1001 so I'm asking this question